# Included template getting loaded before model is available from controller - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a basic tool using vanilla javascript/html/css to perform certain functions across all emails associated with the business. To maintain the code base simplicity, i have started to porting the application using angularJS, creating modules/controllers etc. However, i got stuck with below situation. It looks like from the logs that my included html template gets called before data is ready from the controller.

I am placing an ajax call from the server which roughly takes ~1 sec. But by the time, I guess Angular executes the included template and because of no model availability, it renders nothing on the application side.

A look into my code:

***index.html***

```
<div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="results">
        <section ng-controller = "messageSelectionController" ng-include src="'templates/messageSelectionTemplate.html'"></section>
</div>
```

***messageSelectionController.js***

```
app.controller('messageSelectionController',function($scope,$log){
//Generic ajax call
var makeRequest = function(paramObj,successCallback,errorCallBack,url,type){
$.ajax({
     method : type ? type : "GET",
     url : url ? url : "https://xx.xx.xx/xx/xx",
     data : paramObj,
     xhrFields : { withCredentials : true }
   }).then(successCallback,errorCallBack);
};

var messageSelectionSuccessHandler = function(data){
    $scope.messageselectionlist = JSON.parse(data).response.docs;
    $log.info($scope.messageselectionlist);
};

var messageSelectionErrorHandler = function(data){
    $log.info(data.responseText);
};

var data = {
   q : "",
   fq:[
      'View:xx',
      'Platform:xx'
   ],
   start : 0,
   rows : 9999
};

makeRequest(data, messageSelectionSuccessHandler,messageSelectionErrorHandler);
});
```

***messageSelectionTemplate.html***

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in messageselectionlist">
    <article class="">
      <span class="label label-success">MessageSelection</span>
      <a> "Platform : {{item.Platform}} | View : {{item.View}} | Locale : {{item.Locales[0]}}"
        <i class = "ocon-flag-{{item.Locales[0] | lowercase }}"></i>
      </a>
      <span class = "label label-inverse">{{item.Description}}</span>
    </article>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to put logs to see when the messageSelectionTemplate is loaded, using below code:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event, target){
   console.log(event);  //this $includeContentLoaded event object
   console.log(target); //path to the included resource, 'snippet.html' in this case
});
```

and here's the logs:

```
-----templates/messageSelectionTemplate.html  angular.js:13424
-----Array[654]
```

Can someone let me know how to defer the included template loading until the modal for template is not available. Thanks!

Comment: Use `$http` in place of `$.ajax`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Doing http over ajax would rectify above problem ? Also, I tried to go with `$http` module first, but passing parameters for `GET` call was creating some problem, thus switched back to the basics.. :)

Comment: It should. Angular requires the use of its `$http` module for this exact reason.

Comment: Cant we simply defer included template execution till the time data from model is available?